# Dygraphs with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dygraphs

How can I make the Dygraph charts to take up an entire Bootstrap cell?

It looks like the way to resize charts is by setting their height/width attributes via CSS. However, what I'd like to do is to use Bootstrap columns, and have the chart fit in it completely, like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div id="graphdiv1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div id="graphdiv2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug exactly what's going on without an example link. But if I had to guess...

The default height of a `<div>` with no content is zero pixels. It's likely that what's happening is that your charts are being sized correctly horizontally, but they occupy no space vertically.

The solution is to either add an explicit height:

```css
#graphdiv1, #graphdiv2 {
  height: 400px;
}
```

or otherwise give the `<div>`s some height.